# How to Response WM_MOUSEWHEEL message and scroll the windows in MFC?(vs2012)

Tags: mfc

English is not my native language; please excuse typing errors. 
In my MFC program,I want to Response  WM_MOUSEWHEEL and scroll the windows.
I have search the Google and stackoverflow,but there is not many help.
SO  My question is 
"How to Response  WM_MOUSEWHEEL message and scroll the windows in MFC?(vs2012)"
Many thanks! 
HELU

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add to your MessageMap:

`ON_WM_MOUSEWHEEL()`

in your .h and .cpp file implement:

`afx_msg BOOL OnMouseWheel(UINT nFlags, short zDelta, CPoint pt);`

Tested fast, delta 120 means you scroll up and -120 for scrolling down.